# how to get precise from a pdf file through PHP

Tags: php, pdf, file-read

Is it possible to get only some of the data from a PDF document?
What I want to do in detail, is to export some data from an advertising paper (pdf format) and get all the products and their prices automatically through PHP.

Would this be possible?

I have already tried, reading the pdf files directly through PHP, but the data returned,  is completely messed up.

I have also tried to convert the pdf to html code, but the html code that is generated contains a lot more than just the product name and prices. Also the styling and size of the text is not consistent at all so it is very difficult to check wether it is "some describing text" or a "product name".
Here is an example of some html code generated from a pdf file:

```
// Product name 1
<div style="position:absolute;top:250;left:39"><span class="ft2">MGP CD’en 2015 </span></div>
// Product name 1 end

// Price 1
<div style="position:absolute;top:260;left:39"><span class="ft5">139,-</span></div>
// Price 1 end

<div style="position:absolute;top:71;left:124"><span class="ft8">NYHED</span></div>

// Product name 2
<div style="position:absolute;top:375;left:614"><span class="ft9"> vores </span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;top:397;left:614"><span class="ft9">kyllingeinderfilet </span></div>
// Product name 2 end

<div style="position:absolute;top:422;left:614"><span class="ft3">650 g.</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;top:437;left:614"><span class="ft7">Pr. kg 69,23</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;top:447;left:614"><span class="ft10">Frit valg</span></div>

// Price 2
<div style="position:absolute;top:464;left:614"><span class="ft11">4</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;top:464;left:679"><span class="ft11">5</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;top:464;left:743"><span class="ft11">,-</span></div>
// Price 2 end

<div style="position:absolute;top:250;left:274"><span class="ft12">ÅBENT ALLE DAGE 8.21</span>
```

The above PDF can be seen online at (code above is the page on the right):
http://www.foetex.dk/ugenstilbud/Pages/Aktuel-tilbudsavis.aspx

I hope someone can give some good suggestions on how to get around this problem.
Also, does anyone know a great "pdf to html" converter? The above html code is generated through a free online tool.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mind posting a screenshot of the original pdf? Just to get an idea on how it looks.

Comment: I've edited the question. There is a link to the pdf online

Comment: With this kind of layout it's going to be pretty hard to do what you want. I suggest focussing on the span classes and use these as a reference to what kind of text it actually is. Probebly gonna need to parse the html through some regex to do this. But that still won't cover other problems like which text belongs where etc. Probebly need to parse css position data for that. All in all it'll be hard and complex to code. And probebly won't work very well for multiple pdf files.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was afraid of :( Do you know some good "pdf-to-html converter" library or like, anyways? (not online) Thank you for your answer btw.

Comment: Not directly. But feel free to contact me (email is on profile here) and I'll take a look when home (going there right now). Comments are not meant for lengthy convos :)

Comment: To get access to the words and positions on a PDF page you may take a look at [this](http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-extractor/demos/get-words/) (not free!). Anyhow there's still much logic needed to keep things together as @icecub already said.